# Anonymous task locking

Tags: postgresql, birt

I would like to display 5 tasks (rows) from table every time someone requests new set of tasks (runs BIRT report). Condition is that once task is displayed then the same task cannot be displayed again in next X seconds.

Sample data:

```
/*
-- drop table if exists task_list;

-- Create table for tasks
create table task_list (
  id_task serial,
  task_lock timestamp without time zone
 );

-- Insert some tasks
insert into task_list select * from generate_series(1,100);
*/
```

To achieve required behavior, I created query with `update` inside CTE:

```
with

tasks as (
  update task_list set task_lock = Now()
  where
    id_task in (select id_task 
                from task_list 
                where task_lock is null 
                or task_lock < (Now() - interval '30 seconds') limit 5)
  returning *
)  

select * from tasks;
```

This works perfectly when I run the query repeatedly from pgAdmin, but not when I add this query to BIRT report. This also does not work in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dfb45/5). In both tools, always only first 5 rows are displayed.

Comment: Where in the report did you add this? My gut feeling is that it's called only once (probably when the report is first generated).

Comment: @venite I added this as standard data set (pasted sql directly into query window), using JDBC connection to PostgreSQL. The query gets evaluated every time I hit refresh in the report viewer. I verified this by adding `now()` column to the data set - it works the same way in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dfb45/5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work you have to set `&AutoCommit` property of of data source to `true`

Works in BIRT Designer 4.2.2 and related BIRT Viewer